How to custom event of Drawer in Nuxt Ui 3
I'm try to push a query when drawer UDrawer is open when click 1 UCard. But I don't know where is function click is trigger to custom.
Here is my code, I use Nuxt 3 and Nuxt ui 3
<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps<{
  type: 'free' | 'level' | 'fee' | 'outdated';
  label?: string;
  productId: string;
}>();

const users = ref([1, 2, 3]);
</script>
<template>
  <UDrawer>
    <UCard :ui="{ body: 'p-0' }">
      <MeiBox class="relative">
        <NuxtImg
          src="https://phuongtanphuoc.gov.vn/wp/vietnam/anhdepvietnam%20(24).jpg"
          alt="course image"
          class="w-full h-[181px] object-cover"
        />
        <AtomsTagsOfProductType
          class="absolute top-2 right-2"
          :type="type"
          :label="label"
        />
      </MeiBox>

      <template #footer>
        <MeiBox class="flex flex-col gap-1">
          <MeiText class="text-base font-semibold">
            Khóa học trở thành AI Engineer từ không biết gì
          </MeiText>
          <MeiText class="text-xs font-regular">
            It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by
            the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point
            of
          </MeiText>
          <MeiBox class="flex gap-2 items-center">
            <MeiBox class="flex ml-2">
              <MeiBox
                v-for="(user, index) in users"
                :key="index"
                as="span"
                class="-ml-2"
              >
                <NuxtImg
                  src="https://phuongtanphuoc.gov.vn/wp/vietnam/anhdepvietnam%20(24).jpg"
                  alt="course image"
                  class="size-7 rounded-full"
                />
              </MeiBox>
            </MeiBox>
            <MeiText class="text-xs font-regular"> 120k nguoi hoc </MeiText>
          </MeiBox>
        </MeiBox>
      </template>
    </UCard>
    <template #content>
      <OrganismsResourceInfoDrawer
        :product-id="productId"
        class="max-w-[calc(100vh_-_104px)] shadow-none"
      />
    </template>
  </UDrawer>
</template>

<style scoped></style>

UDrawer component is Drawer component of NuxtUI 3, UCard component is Card component of NuxtUI 3. When I click Card, Drawer successful appear but I want add a query like ?id=productId but I don't know why?

see the API documentation for UDrawer.  It emits update:open when clicked open.  You can use this event to do what you want.
